# Should I put the ScriptBlock inside the foreach loop?

Tags: powershell

I was setting up some parallelization and wondered if there was a benefit (or detriment) to placing the ScriptBlock inside the foreach loop. Like so...

```
for ($currentJob = 0; $currentJob -le 20; $currentJob++) {
    $jobBlock = {
        param ([int] $runCount)
        Write-Host "running... $runCount"
        for($i = 0; $i -lt 100000; $i++ ) {
        }
    }

    Write-Host "Starting job for $currentJob"
    Start-Job -ScriptBlock $jobBlock -ArgumentList $running.Count
}
```

... or is outside better?

```
$jobBlock = {
    param ([int] $runCount)
    Write-Host "running... $runCount"
    for($i = 0; $i -lt 100000; $i++ ) {
    }
}

for ($currentJob = 0; $currentJob -le 20; $currentJob++) {
    Write-Host "Starting job for $currentJob"
    Start-Job -ScriptBlock $jobBlock -ArgumentList $running.Count
}
```

I come from the C# world and the "inside job" looks like something would get lost or overwritten or left to the garbage collector inappropriately.

Just wondering about the nuances of PowerShell.

Comment: If speed matters, take runspaces instead of jobs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're not using any of the variables from the `for` statement in the `$jobBlock`, there's no need to redefine it each time through the loop; define it outside.